# appcelerator post request. Send one variable few times in one request.

Tags: variables, post, appcelerator

Hallo! I want to send variable few times(each time with different value) in one post query.
In HTML form it works and looks like:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/index.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="line_item" value="value1">
    <input type="hidden" name="line_item" value="value2">
    <input type="hidden" name="line_item" value="value3">    
</form>
```

But appcelerator sends only the last value in this code:

```
var httpClient = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    var params = {
            line_item:'value1',
            line_item:'value2',
            line_item:'value3',
    };
httpClient.open('POST', 'http://localhost/index.php');
httpClient.send(params);
```

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Sorry, I forgot to mention that I don't have access to server and I need it solved in appcelerator.

Answer (score 0):

if you use PHP as server platform, you can join POST-variables to array

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/index.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="line_item[]" value="value1">
    <input type="hidden" name="line_item[]" value="value2">
    <input type="hidden" name="line_item[]" value="value3">    
</form>
```

and then process it like array in php:

```
if (is_array($_POST['line_item[]'])) {
  $count = 0;
  foreach($_POST['line_item[]'] as $line_item) 
    echo($line_item . " #" . $count++);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I don't have access to server and I need it solved in appcelerator.

Answer (score 0):

Solved...

```
var httpClient = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
httpClient.open('POST', 'http://localhost/index.php');
httpClient.send("line_item=value1&line_item=value2&line_item=value3");
```